# CKEditor CDN script not working, even though everything is correct

Tags: python, flask, ckeditor

I was following a tutorial on YouTube for flask web app creation and now am stuck...Does anyone know why the CKEditor CDN script doesn't work for me?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, You need to provide more details by checkin your network tab or console tab in inspector, see what kind of errors is there and mention it you question.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was, that the CKEditor CDN script got tangled in another self-closing script

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you don't define Textarea in HTML tags so where from CKEditor find id which name is the editor.

like

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is your answer complete?